# django-cms child plugin not registering

Tags: python, django, django-cms

In cms_plugins.py I have a parent plugin and child plugin

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from banner_plugin.models import BannerPluginModel, BannerItem
from banner_plugin.admin import BannerInlineAdmin, BannerLinksInlineAdmin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


class CMSBannerParentPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = BannerPluginModel  # model where plugin data are saved
    module = _("Banners")
    name = _("Banner Parent Plugin")  # name of the plugin in the interface
    render_template = "djangocms_banner/banner_parent_plugin.html"
    allow_chldren = True
    child_classes = ['CMSBannerChildPlugin']

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance': instance})
        return context


plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSBannerParentPlugin) 

class CMSBannerChildPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = BannerItem  # model where plugin data are saved
    module = _("Banners")
    name = _("Banner Child Plugin")  # name of the plugin in the interface
    render_template = "djangocms_banner/banner_child_plugin.html"
    parent_classes = ['CMSBannerParentPlugin']
    inlines = (BannerLinksInlineAdmin,)

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance': instance})
        return context

 # register the plugin
plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSBannerChildPlugin)
```

When I runs the project only the `Banner Parent Plugin` appears in the module `Banners`. what could be the error. Both `banner_parent_plugin.html` and `banner_child_plugin.html` exists.

In models.py I have

```
class BannerPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
     // no fields here

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Banners"


class BannerItem(CMSPlugin):
    // fields goes here

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.heading


class BannerLinks(models.Model):
    // fields goes here
    banner_item = models.ForeignKey(to=BannerItem, related_name="links", null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in your code to fix a small issue:

`allow_chldren = True` should be `allow_children = True`

As you are working with classes, this does not through an exception.

Not sure if your code have any more issue, try this and keep us updated.

Good luck